# Clicking "use-ajax" locks JS on page on slower devices until done. How to replace with $.ajax?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a large form that is often used but takes 2-3 seconds to load. To get around this, I have it loaded by clicking the `<a id="doc_ready_link" class="use-ajax"` link with JS on page load.

```
document.querySelector('#doc_ready_link').click();
```

Module

```
function custom_ajax_page_st_form_menu() {
  $items['class-content-form'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'ajax_content_response',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

On faster machines like my laptop or phone, this is fine and I have a fast page load and a spinner on the form link.
But on slower laptops and phones, other JS stuff like the menu doesn't work until it's loaded giving a bad UX.

How do I get that form loaded with ajax after page load without locking up the browser? For a normal click, the UX is ok but when it's all hidden like what I'm doing, the clunkiness is jarring.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have tried the other methods below for clicking the link but the locking of other JS remains on slower devices. I'm still looking for some other method, most likely a snippet of `$.ajax` code that can call my module's code just like `class="use-ajax"` does.

PS for anyone wondering how to click Flags etc. in Drupal:

`document.querySelector('#').click();` works when `$('#').click();` usually doesn't.

Edit: For what it's worth, this is the module that the "use-ajax" link calls but I don't think it matters much.

```
<?php

function custom_ajax_page_st_form_form_init()
{
    drupal_add_js('misc/jquery.form.js');
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function custom_ajax_page_st_form_menu()
{
    // A menu callback is required when using ajax outside of the Form API.
    $items['class-content-form'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'ajax_content_response',
        //   'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array(
            'access content'
        ),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
}

function ajax_content_response($type = 'ajax', $nid = 0, $node_type = "", $home_nid)
{

    $output = _custom_page_st_form_loader();
    if ($type == 'ajax') {
        $commands   = array();
        $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#class_form_load', '<div id="class_form_load">' . $output . '</div>');
        //    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.add_menu', 'show');
        // Remove Spinner
        $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('html', 'trigger', array(
            'remove_ajax_spinner'
        ));
        // Set Groups Audience
        if ($nid != 0) {
            $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-og-group-ref-und-0-default', 'val', array(
                $nid
            ));
            $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-og-group-ref-und-0-default', 'trigger', array(
                "chosen:updated"
            ));
        }
        // Set Home
        if ($nid != 0) {
            if ($node_type == "homepage_group") {
                $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.form-item-field-home-und input', 'prop', array(
                    "checked",
                    true
                ));

            } // $(".form-item-field-home-und input").prop("checked", true)
        }
        // Set Homepage Audience
        $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-field-homepage-audience-und-0-default', 'val', array(
            $home_nid
        ));
        $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('#edit-field-homepage-audience-und-0-default', 'trigger', array(
            "chosen:updated"
        ));


        $page = array(
            '#type' => 'ajax',
            '#commands' => $commands
        );
        ajax_deliver($page);
    } else {
        $output = '<div id="class_form_load">' . $output . '</div>';
        return $output;
    }
}

function _custom_page_st_form_loader()
{
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = node_add('class_content');
    return drupal_render($form);

}
```

And the reason this is a big deal for my site. There are 8 JS buttons that users click very quickly on the site and all break on slow devices.

[image: Top of site]

Comment: By page load do you mean window or document load?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($){

Comment: you've completely changed the question !!! :( . it's more better revert it to the start question and ask this as another question, this is a type of disregard our effort and care for people question, this means our time is not important for you.

Comment: Hi @zhilevan, I think you've misunderstood my original question. It hasn't changed but now, I'm just giving what I think is probably the way to do it with `$.ajax`. It's also more generic which is good for SE. My original question was `How to replace a "use-ajax" link that's auto-clicked on page load?`. I thought I made it clear that I wanted that functionality replaced and that I had a working solution very similar to the two provided. They still lock the browser on slower machines because they still use the "use-ajax" link I want replaced with something else.

Comment: Please check the original question which I updated literally on your advice below. I don't know why you'd suggest that I have disregard for your efforts when I also contribute a lot to this community. I will look at all of this again tomorrow. It's 1am here.

Comment: Well, yes I've misunderstood,  is this true "you want to prevent loading form in page loading, and after page loads, you call an ajax endpoint(menu) and retrieve the Form Items and inject into the page? "

Comment: Yep, the form has a lot slowloading fields. I need it loaded in the background since the UX of the two alternatives (on actual page/on click) is pretty bad. I figure I just need to add something to a basic $.ajax and let my existing module work as it does already.

Comment: So Now you want I provide an ajax jquery call your endpoint in order to retrieve form elements form your route `class-content-form` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60292/discussion-between-niall-murphy-and-zhilevan).

Comment: Hey @NiallMurphy, did you try the updated/corrected code snippet below? I see you updated the question, but it would be great to know if that worked for you in the end. Cheers

Comment: Hi Stephanos, unfortunately the browser still lock up and the UX spoiled. I think this is something I won't be able to get rid of.  It happens for any click of a "use-ajax" link with a substantial form to be loaded.

Comment: In my experience it has been fairly quick. What are the contents of `ajax_content_response`? Did you also mean to change the `delivery callback` to `ajax_deliver` too? See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_deliver/7.x

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've updated my answer with my module code. I use ajax_deliver. I guess it really is the size of the form and the fact that because it isn't the user clicking the "use-ajax", the page slowdown is jarring. It makes the site feel broken. I'm going to read through your answer now.

Comment: I don't see ajax_deliver specified. If you're not setting the delivery callback to that handler, it's using the default callback.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really that good at all this.. Is my ajax_deliver($page) line different to what you mean by setting the delivery callback?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `window.onload` if you want to have your code run after other javascript code (and DOM and CSS) have been loaded. `window.onload` is triggered after `document.onready`.

> The ready event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while
>   the onload event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has
>   been loaded.
>
> The onload event is a standard event in the DOM, while the ready event
>   is specific to jQuery. The purpose of the ready event is that it
>   should occur as early as possible after the document has loaded, so
>   that code that adds functionality to the elements in the page doesn't
>   have to wait for all content to load.

[quoted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698214/5875098]

As an example (and to be more Drupal-specific), the following javascript should cover what you need:

```
(function ($) {    
  Drupal.behaviors.yourModule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('body').once('bind-window-load', function(){
        $(window).bind('load', function() {
          $('#doc_ready_link').click();
        });
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Binding to window load inside a behavior is incorrect. Behaviors add functionality to the markup in "context", this will needlessly bind events to window every time Drupal.attachBehaviors is called, possibly a lot of times for each page load.

Comment: Hey @Sam152, thanks for having a look, I updated the supplied code using `once()`, to avoid binding multiple times.

Comment: Hi Stefanos, thanks for the answer but this snippet didn't actually click the link as needed whereas zhilevan's did. But even then, the performance issue remains and JS gets locked up until the form is loaded. Now I'm not sure if it's a site issue or something with the way these links work.


Also, it seems you need document.querySelector('#').click(); to click use-ajax links in Drupal. I can use that for Flags / Rules links when jQuery doesn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @NiallMurphy, there was an error - late addtion - to the code, that I corrected, I called `once()` on the window, but it should be called on a DOM object. I tested it and it should work for you too know, have another try. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hi everybody I coming back ;)

According to

## Events

`$(document).on('ready', handler)` binds to the ready event from jQuery. The handler is called **when the DOM is loaded**. Assets like **images maybe still are missing**. It will never be called if the document is ready at the time of binding. jQuery uses the [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)-Event for that, emulating it if not available.

`$(document).on('load', handler)` is an event that will be fired once all **resources are loaded** from the server. Images are loaded now. While [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) is a raw HTML event, [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is built by jQuery.

## Functions

`$(document).ready(handler)` actually is a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/). **The handler will be called immediately if document is ready at the time of calling.** Otherwise it binds to the `ready`-Event.

[Before jQuery 1.8](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733), `$(document).load(handler)` existed as an alias to `$(document).on('load',handler)`.

## Further Reading

- [The timing](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/08/document-ready-vs-window-onload.html)
- [On the function ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [An example](http://jsfiddle.net/2RyKn/1/)
- [Promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)
- [The removed event alias](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11733)

The @Stephan solution is not wrong but it's better you don't wait for all resources ( I mean all images etc ) load when  your Menu Item ( DOM objects) loaded **So**

```
(function ($) {    
  Drupal.behaviors.yourModule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        $('#doc_ready_link').click();
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

**NOTE1:** As you know `Drupal.behaviors` acts like `$(document).ready` on Drupal so imagine *Bind on windows.load event in document.ready event binding*.

**NOTE2** if you have some ajax call it cause duplication calling of this form and for [preventing duplication triggering](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91606/how-to-prevent-behavior-attached-functions-from-being-attached-twice)(although in your case not required because you redirect page to another page immediately ) **So**

```
(function ($) {    
  Drupal.behaviors.yourModule = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
        $('body', context).once('myModule', function () {
        $('#doc_ready_link').click();

});
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Drupal.behaviors is not at all like document ready. Document ready is just the first time behaviors are invoked (on the whole document). It's an API for attaching functionality to any arbitary chunk of DOM. It's invoked any time new elements are inserted into the DOM, possibly a lot of times over the lifetime of the page.

Comment: @Sam152 ```Any function defined as a property of Drupal.behaviors will get called when the DOM has loaded. drupal.js has a $(document).ready() function which calls the Drupal.attachBehaviors() function, which in turn cycles through the Drupal.behaviors object calling every one of its properties, these all being functions declared by various modules as above, and passing in the document as the context.
```
ref : https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: @Sam152 another reference https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal

Comment: Hi @zhilevan, great answer and I feel awful for saying that while the code works, the locking remains while the form is loaded. I think I need a totally different approach to the "use-ajax" link. Just some regular $.ajax on page load. `$.ajax({url: $('#doc_ready_link').attr('href'), success: function(result){ console.log( "yes" );  }});` successfully prints "yes" but the form doesn't get loaded. I feel like there has to be a way to do this without the specific link.

Comment: @NiallMurphy maybe  `.click`  doesn't redirect to another page.  maybe `on('click' , ... ` is a better option, by the way, you can ask it as another question or update your question with extra section and describe this issue, I'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what your form is doing, but perhaps the request and delivery callback is doing too much work. In my comment I had mentioned changing the delivery callback to ajax deliver. Here is an example:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kevinquillen/4c5df0e5f9c586182117/raw/1190acbc27b3192c33b87788f5a1f1c35f98b3c6/dynamic-reveal.example.php

```
function user_alert_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['js/user-alert/get-message/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'user_alert_display_alert',
    'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function user_alert_display_alert($nid) {
  $output = '';

  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
  $query->entityCondition('bundle', 'user_alert');
  $query->propertyCondition('nid', $nid);
  $query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
  $query->propertyOrderBy('nid', 'DESC');
  $query->range(0, 1);

  $result = $query->execute();

  if ($result['node']) {
    $record = reset($result['node']);
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $record->nid);
    $output = theme('user_alert', array('node' => $wrapper->value()));
  }

  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('div#user-alert-message', $output);
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('div#user-alert-message', 'foundation', array('reveal', 'open'));
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

On the front end, there are link(s) with the `use-ajax` class that trigger this behavior. The callbacks only function is what you see above, and despite doing an EFQ and a `theme` call, it was pretty quick. The end result here is the themed output is injected to a hidden div, and then a modal plugin opens that div.

You can also use `$.ajax` too, since you are just hitting a menu item route.

Comment: I will have to look at this later today and write a delivery callback function and change up my code (which I added to the original question). Thanks.